# Given a Hypothesis Strategy, can I get the minimal example?

Tags: python-hypothesis

I'd like to get the minimum for a complicated class, for which I have already written a strategy.

Is it possible to ask hypothesis to simply give me the minimum example for a given strategy?

Context here is writing a strategy and a default minimum (for use in `@hypothesis.example`) - surely the information for the latter is already contained in the former?

```py
import dataclasses
import hypothesis
from hypothesis import strategies

@dataclasses.dataclass
class Foo:
    bar: int
    # Foo has many more attributes which are strategised over...

    @classmethod
    def strategy(cls):
        return hypothesis.builds(cls, bar=strategies.integers())

    @classmethod
    def minimal(cls):
        return hypothesis.minimal(cls.strategy())
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer.
Use `hypothesis.find`:

> """Returns the minimal example from the given strategy `specifier` that
> matches the predicate function `condition`.

So we want the following code for the above example:

```py
minimal = hypothesis.find(
    specifier=Foo.strategy(),
    condition=lambda _: True,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that `hypothesis.find(s, lambda _: True)` is the way to do this.

---

> Context here is writing a strategy and a default minimum (for use in `@hypothesis.example()`) - surely the information for the latter is already contained in the former?

It's not just contained in it, but generating examples will *almost always* start by generating the minimal example* - because if that fails, we can stop immediately!  So you might not need to do this at all ;-)

(the rare exceptions are strategies with complicated filters, where the attempted-minimal example is rejected by a filter - and we just move on to reasonably-minimal examples rather than shrinking to find the minimal one)

---

I'd also note that [`st.builds()` has native support for dataclasses](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.builds), so you can omit the strategies (or pass `hypothesis.infer`) for any argument where you don't have more specific constraints than "any instance of the type".  For example, there's no need to pass `bar=st.integers()` above!